# c# uwp custom tooltip

Tags: c#, uwp, tooltip

In C# UWP, does anyone know how to make custom tooltip, with arrow pointing to control that is tooltip bounded.

Like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC510746.png))</sub>

I have tried to change a style.

Comment: I guess you've seen this link already: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/creating-fancy-tooltips-in-wpf/ not sure if it will help for the "arrow form"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** This answer may not be the right way to do it but it will work

### Method 1:

Use [`Polygon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/drawing-shapes#polygon) to draw the border of the `ToolTip`. Use [`Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/drawing-shapes#path) if you want to have curved edges. Here is a code sample.

```
<Button Content="?" ToolTipService.Placement="Bottom">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
            <Grid>
                <Polygon Fill="Gainsboro" Points="0,20,0,120,200,120,200,20,110,20,100,0,90,20" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" />
                <StackPanel Margin="5,25,5,5">
                    <TextBlock Text="Information" FontSize="36" Foreground="Blue"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="This is a button" FontSize="18"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </ToolTip>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

**Sample Output:**

[image]

### Method 2:

You can use a custom designed [`Image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/images-imagebrushes) to be as a border for your `ToolTip`. Don't forget to set `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` and `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`. Here is a code sample.

```
<Button Content="?" ToolTipService.Placement="Bottom">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="Assets/ToolTipImage.png" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                <StackPanel Margin="5,25,5,5">
                    <TextBlock Text="Information" FontSize="36" Foreground="Blue"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="This is a button" FontSize="18"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </ToolTip>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

Comment: Well, thanx. This gave me some more ideas on how to continue my work.

Comment: I will just have to make calculations where to show arrow.